# Initializing ViewModel in fragment Android java

Tags: java, android, mvvm, fragment, android-jetpack

I am trying to initialize my viewmodel object in the `FirstFragment.java` file of `BasicActivity`. All theses four codes are failed. The documentation could not help me much.

```
mViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel.class);
mViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(MyViewModel.class);
mViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(getActivity()).get(MyViewModel.class);
mViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(FirstFragment.class).get(MyViewModel.class);
```

On the other hand, `public ViewModelProvider(@NonNull ViewModelStoreOwner owner)` ViewModelProvider is taking ViewModelStoreOwner as its parameter and in the `FragmentActivity.java` `ViewModelStore getViewModelStore()` method of `ViewModelStore` interface is implemented may be in a factory pattern.

```
@NonNull
        @Override
        public ViewModelStore getViewModelStore() {
            return FragmentActivity.this.getViewModelStore();
        }
```

Help me initializing ViewModel

Comment: "All theses four codes are failed" - do you get runtime errors? If yes, what error messages are there in Logcat? And please show more of your code/ project structure (what about the ViewModel? and its parent class, constructor, ...) *TL;DR* please add enough information so that we can set up a small sample app and try to reproduce the error

Comment: I have solved it. actually it was room annotation dependency which was failing me to create the database singletone object and eventually failing to initialize the viewmodel.

Comment: @Manan if my answer helped you or if it is correct according to your question, please, considere accepting it :)

Answer (score 6):

Initializing your viewModel goes like:

if you are using

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
```

and Intialize your viewModel

```
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this,viewModelFactory).get(MyViewModel.class);
```

but it's deprecated now. 
So update the dependency to:

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
```

and initial your viewModel as follow:

```
viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this,viewModelFactory).get(MyViewModel.class);
```

viewModelFactory is optional.

Comment: ViewModelProviders is depreciated. In the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProviders) it is told to use the ViewModelProvider constructor directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize it like this:

```kotlin
class FooFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var viewModel: MyViewModel

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[MyViewModel::class.java]
    }
}
```

Now, if your viewmodel receives a parameter, you can do it like this:

```kotlin
class MyViewModel(application, Application, bar: Bar) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

}
```

```
class FooViewModelFactory(val application: Application, val foo: Foo): ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory(application) {

    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return FooViewModel(application, foo) as T
    }
}
```